# How to close / dispose Gibraltar agent of Nlog?

Tags: c#, nlog, dispose

How to close / Dispose  the working thread  of [Gibraltar agent for Nlog](https://nlog-project.org/2009/11/01/gibraltar-adapter-for-nlog-released.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Gibraltar.Agent.Log.EndSession();
```